# Is there a difference between a (general) pattern and a string pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a list `myList` that contains several strings. I wish to use [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) to find the positions of strings in `myList` that match the pattern `"A" ~~ ___`.

The first overload for [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) is:

> `Position[expr, pattern]`
> gives a list of the positions at which objects matching *pattern* appear in *expr*.

Is there a difference between a (general) pattern and a *string* pattern?  In the following code, why does the first call to `Position` yield an empty list (`{}`), while the second call to `Position` gives the positions of the strings in `myList` that match `"A" ~~ ___`?

```
myList = {"AB", "B", "AABB", "BAA", "ABB"};
Position[myList, "A" ~~ ___, {1}, Heads -> False]
Position[myList, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "A" ~~ ___] &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> {}

> {{1}, {3}, {5}}

Is `"A" ~~ ___` not a pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a difference. `"A" ~~ ___` is not a pattern but a [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html), which you can see by observing its `FullForm`:

```
"A" ~~ ___ // FullForm
StringExpression["A", BlankNullSequence[]]
```

`StringExpression` is used as an analog of `Pattern` for strings (more about [Working with String Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html)).

Therefore, there are two different functions: [`MatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchQ.html) (with corresponding `Position`) and [`StringMatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html) (with corresponding `StringPosition`). While `MatchQ`  expects a pattern, `StringMatchQ` expects a `StringExpression` (or `RegularExpression`), which is mentioned under the first bullet point in *Details and Options*.

Answer (score 1):

As Domen already pointed out, Pattern and StringExpression differ. Therefore, what you can do, is to use a pattern together with a PatternTest that request a boolean function. As boolean function you choose:

```
StringMatchQ[#, "A" ~~ ___] &
```

With this the pattern looks like:

```
_?(StringMatchQ[#, "A" ~~ ___] &)
```

Now you approach works:

```
myList = {"AB", "B", "AABB", "BAA", "ABB"};
Position[myList, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "A" ~~ ___] &), {1},Heads -> False]

{{1}, {3}, {5}}
```